# Execute at coordinates relative to command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm creating an RPG map and I need a command block to detect if a player is near specific coordinates, but I cannot work with specific numbers, I need it to be relative to the command block position. For example, in this command that does not work:

```
/execute at block ~3 ~2 ~-1 run execute if entity @p[team=Player01,distance=..5]
```

The current command I'm using is this one:

```
/execute if entity @a[team=Player01,distance=..5]
```

I've already searched about execute relative to command block but it´s the opposite scenario. I need the detection to be relative to the command block.

Comment: What is your actual problem? If you can detect players being nearby, you can also do anything to players nearby. What does not work about your first command? And what do you actually want to do? The two commands you listed don't perform any action.

Comment: the problem is that with sphere radius the corners don´t detect the player and i do not know how to use square radius

Comment: i need the detection área to be a cube

Comment: So it's the exact same thing as your other question?

Comment: The only way yo make it a cube is using one command block for each block and instead of using comparators, you should learn a little bit more about /tag and @e[tag="name"] selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you are missing is the positioned part. It will work from a certain position and it can be an entity, coordinate or relative coordinate.

Thus, it will look like this:

```
/execute positioned ~ ~ ~ run execute as @a[team=Player01,distance=..1] run [Rest of the command here]
```

Simply change "~ ~ ~" to your desired relative coordinates.

Altough, it will work in a radius of 1 since using 0 here will anulate the effect (or make it waaaay specific becoming useless), for some reason.

Comment: it´s not working i don´t know why

Comment: Are you sure that the command is a repeater and set to always active?

Comment: /execute positioned ~-1 ~2 ~1 run execute as @a[team=Player01,distance=..5] run is what im using in this specific command

Comment: yes i´m sure it´s on repeat and Always active

Comment: But what are you using after the run? What you want the command block to do? You are missing the rest of you command since you didn't especify in your question

Comment: Try /execute positioned ~-1 ~2 ~1 run execute as @a[team=Player01,distance=..5] run say a

Comment: k i´ll test, the only and one thing i need is the command block to detect the player in the  command execution radius

Comment: it Works if i type run say a but i need it only to detect the player so the comparator activates

Comment: i tried removing the "run" but it did nothing

Comment: Change it to /execute positioned ~-1 ~2 ~1 run execute if entity @a[team=Player01,distance=..5]